# Sequence field in django model without primary_key

Tags: django, model, integer, sequence

I need another sequence field in model this fild will start from 100000 and need to be incremented but django AutoField need to be primary_key, any way to do a sequence without be a PK ?

thnkx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are these going to be unique as well? in what way are they different from the pk field?

if all you need is for them to start at 100000, could you get away with using `pk + 100000`?

Comment: Sure this is the current solution, but if a need a manual sequence is that possible ? o any sequence must br PK in django?

Comment: manual sequence? you can always add a PositiveIntegerField and set it manually. Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Manual is not good, i want a sequence without need to be PK, but for now the best solution is the manual PK + 10000 thnkx